# How to resolve timeout issues between 2 applications ?

Tags: timeout

My application is communicating with a service. The service provides user login , registration , update functionality (IAM Service) . Since, this feature is critical & we don't want to impact user performance, we set the timeout 500 millisec, considering the fact that both my application & the IAM service are in the same data center.

On analysis, we found that the IAM service on an average takes 10 - 12 millisecs & my application which simply sends the request takes 1 - 2 millisecs. Also, it does not happen for every request, just a few request.

The network engineer says the network is good & there are no leaks.

Request your inputs to understand, how should I proceed to analyze the root cause to recognize which component is taking time.

Answer (score 0):

- Make sure the Application and the Service are synchronized (have the same time stamp)
- Log the Time stamp of  request being sent by the App
- Observe the time stamp when the request hits the wire
- Log the Time stamp when the Request is being received by the Service
- Log the time stamp when the Service sends out the response
- Observe the time stamp when the response hits the wire
- Log the time stamp when the app receives the response

The next time the timeout occurs - check the log to find out which two laterally adjacent time stamps have a difference of more than the 500ms. Now once you have the profiled information - focus on the particular segment that causes the timeout.

Comment: Thanks Abhi. The 2 systems have a different timestamp. My application is running in BST (UK Timezone) & the service is in PST (US Timezone).

Comment: Can you modify your log function to change the timestamp? - say the Application  time stamp is printed in PST.  Make sure you take in consideration the time stamp of the network monitor too.BTW, if your "few" request is a very small number - you may to consider doing the time stamp conversion ... in a python script that will scan the log files and the network monitor dump.

Comment: You can `send` your logs to Loggly.com - try them out - I am NOT associated with them.